# bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, automake

I'm building autoconf-2.68.

I'm not very familiar with this tool. However, after analysing the Makefiles,
I find that the build fails when running the script `autoconf-2.68/bin/autom4te`.

I'm having this error:

```
bash: ./autom4te :/home/user/workspace/output: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Some analysis that I have done

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

In the autom4te I find this line in the BEGIN function

```
$ENV{'SHELL'} = '/bin/sh' if ($^O eq 'dos');
```

Could this cause a problem? Any idea to resolve?

**Edit**

The first lines of autom4te are:

```
#! /home/user/Workspace/output/xx_yyyyyyy_pp88_tttttt_uuuuuuu_aaa_bbbbbbb/host/usr/bin/perl -w
# -*- perl -*-
# Generated from autom4te.in; do not edit by hand.

eval 'case $# in 0) exec /home/user/Workspace/output/xx_yyyyyyy_pp88_tttttt_uuuuuuu_aaa_bbbbbbb/host/usr/bin/perl -S "$0";; *) exec /home/user/Workspace/output/xx_yyyyyyy_pp88_tttttt_uuuuuuu_aaa_bbbbbbb/host/usr/bin/perl -S "$0" "$@";; esac'
if 0;
```

The script caller:

```
autoconf.in: $(srcdir)/autoconf.as $(m4sh_m4f_dependencies)
    $(MY_AUTOM4TE) --language M4sh --cache '' --melt $(srcdir)/autoconf.as -o $@
```

`MY_AUTOM4TE` is defined as:

```
MY_AUTOM4TE = \
    autom4te_perllibdir='$(top_srcdir)'/lib                 \
    AUTOM4TE_CFG='$(AUTOM4TE_CFG)'         $(top_builddir)/bin/autom4te \
        -B '$(top_builddir)'/lib -B '$(top_srcdir)'/lib        # keep ` '
```

Comment: What is the first line of the `autom4te` script?

Comment: Did you extract the `autoconf` package on a Windows system and then copy it  to your Linux system?

Comment: @xhienne, I update the question with the 1st line of script.

Comment: @roaima, No the package is extracted and then build from a linux machine

Comment: @Mouin And does `/home/user/Workspace/host/usr/bin/perl` exist and is executable by you?

Comment: @xhienne, yes it exists i tried a simple "hello world" example and it executes as expected. BTW the autom4te is shell script isn't ? why it does not start with #!/bin/bash

Comment: @Mouin it's a Perl script that has a line of (`bash`) shell script at the beginning in case the shell doesn't recognise the `#!` marker and tries to run it directly. Please test the `perl` installation with this command → `/home/user/Workspace/host/usr/bin/perl -e 'print "Hello, world\n" '`

Comment: @roaima, Thanks, I think i find the problem, the makefile that invokes `autom4te` doesn't use `perl autom4te` it just call `autom4te`, i think this is what is missing. just some questions. 1- if autom4te is a perl script why it does not have `.perl` extension 2- could u please explain "in case the shell doesn't recognise the #! marker and tries to run it directl"

Comment: @Mouin Can you please show us the output of `hexdump -C -n 48 autom4te`? I suspect there is something wrong with the beginning of this file (the first line, the "interpreter" part). Can you also show us where and how the `./autom4te` script is called (an relevant excerpt of the calling script).

Comment: @xhienne, I edit the question, the problem come from the name of the folder "xx_yyyyyyy_pp88_tttttt_uuuuuuu_aaa_bb" I avoided to  write the full path because it's confidential. any way the problem come from the fact that path is too long that explains the error output : `/home/user/workspace/output` it stops in output instead of `home/user/Workspace/output/xx_yyyyyyy_pp88_tttttt_uuuuuuu_aaa_bbbbbbb/host/usr/bin/perl` Thanks again

Comment: So your problem is solved, right?

Comment: @xhienne yes, thanks i have to prepare an answer. just i'am wondering why this size limit for the path

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the interpreter line in `autom4te`:

```
#! /home/user/Workspace/output/xx_yyyyyyy_pp88_tttttt_uuuuuuu_aaa_bbbbbbb/host/usr/bin/perl -w
```

It seems that the path is too long.

That explain the error output:

```
bash: ./autom4te :/home/user/workspace/output: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It stops on `output` and can't read the full path of the interpreter.
By changing the path of the interpreter(short path) :

```
#! /home/user/Workspace/output/xxx/host/usr/bin/perl -w
```

The problem is resolved.